# ajax returns error when ajax code is inside button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax code to hit url works fine when the code is placed inside document.ready() function. But when the same code placed inside button click function inside ready fun() ajax url returns error.

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(initialize);
    function initialize() {
        $(".storage").click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                  cache:    false,
                  type:     "GET",
                  async:    true,
                  dataType: "JSON",
                  url:      "urllink",
                  data:     { apiKey: "apikey" },
                  success:  function(results) { 
                       alert(" Disk Array URL hit");
                  }
                  error:    function(xhr)     { alert("Error!") } });
             });
        }
  </script>

  <input type="submit" value="LOAD" id="storage" class="storage" >
```

Comment: Syntax error as "," is missing after success callback..

Comment: that is typo in the code, comma was there in the code. but still it hits error only when it is inside button click.. if the same code is inside document.ready it works fine.

Comment: What url is `url: "urllink"`. Is `urllink` an actual link/page? Also, since you have `dataType: "JSON"`, if your returned data from `url: "urllink"` is invalid json then it will error out. have you checked your browser console to see if your url is being hit, and what is being returned?

Comment: yes urllink is confidential API url .It has valid json data. This url is hit and data is returned successfully when the code is inside ready() function. The same code when placed inside button click, it hits the error path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function initialize()
            {
                    $(".storage").click(function()
                    {
                            $.ajax({
                                    cache   : false,
                                    type    : "GET",
                                    async   : true,
                                    dataType: "JSON",
                                    url     : "urllink",
                                    data    : {apiKey: "apikey"},
                                    success : function(results)
                                    {
                                            alert(" Disk Array URL hit");
                                    },
                                    error   : function(xhr)
                                    {
                                            alert("Error!")
                                    }
                            });
                    });
            }
            $(document).ready(initialize);
<input type="button" value="LOAD" id="storage" class="storage" >
```

Input Type submit will submit a form which is not the expected action in this script.. "," was missing after success argument..which was giving syntax error..

Comment: i have form also to post to different page after button click..                       <form  method="post" name="myform" action="dbconnect.php"> ... the problem here is, as soon as i click the button it post to dbconnect.php page without hiting the url inside the ajax code.

Comment: You can not perform this 2 actions on the same event..Try to submit the form after ajax success callback...

Comment: ok..I will try to call php page inside ajax success call.    $('form').attr('action', 'dbconnect.php');              $('form').submit();   .. is this the correct way to call the php page inside ajax success ?

Comment: All you need to do is submit your form using submit() js method as you get ajax success response..